# How to pass $scope data between two partial files in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

How can I pass data in two partial html files using angularJS, totally weird cant get through it.

I have one index file [fine.], I login and reach view5 [partials/blog.html] which is written in DemoCtrl [Fine], all works fine till now. Now when I click on the link in blog.html, it goes to next page but doesnt show any $scope data which I have set in the controller.

***HTML code of partial file:***
        
            
                {{post.postText}}

```
    <div class="blog-meta clearfix">
     <p class="pull-left">
         <i class="icon-user"></i> by <a href="#">{{ post.firstName }} {{ post.lastName }}</a> | <i class="icon-folder-close"></i> Category <a href="#">Food</a> | <i class="icon-calendar"></i> {{post.createdDate.millis | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}
     </p>
     <p class="pull-right"><i class="icon-comment pull"></i> <a href="#/view18#comments" data-ng-click="postDetails(post)">3 Comments</a></p>
     </div>
```

***Controller Code ***

```
    app.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', 'Post', 'ezfb', '$window', 'PFactory', 'PostFactory', '$location', '$timeout', function ($scope, Post, ezfb, $window, PFactory, PostFactory, $location, $timeout) {
        $scope.postDetails = function (post) {
                $scope.postdetail = {id: null};
                $scope.postdetail = post;
                $location.path('/view18');
            }
    }]);
```

*** app.js ***

```
    $routeProvider.when('/view5', {templateUrl: 'nova/blog.html', controller: 'DemoCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.when('/view18', {templateUrl: 'nova/blog-item.html', controller: 'DemoCtrl18'});
```

postDetails(post) method in called in DemoCtrl with post object and that post object is been set in $scope.postdetail variable in $scope.postDetail method and view is different template. I can see data coming fine in console in the controller and postDetails method but it is not displayed in template.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access data set to scope in one controller in another controller/template.

Use a service and hold/set data in the service and use the service in your DemoCtrl18 to get the data that you set in DemoCtrl

Or use angaular ui-router to get more features like parent-child states and scope inheritance and more.